# What is the result of `ls -al /` on a default Debian install?

Tags: debian

After [screwing up my Debian install](https://serverfault.com/questions/77277/can-i-recover-from-rm), I was wondering if someone could just quickly run:

```
ls -al /
```

On their Debian server, so I can compare it with mine. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just performed a Debian 5.0 amd64 install.  This is what I have in /

```
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:23 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:42 boot
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    11 2009-10-22 12:22 cdrom -> media/cdrom
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  3240 2009-10-22 12:53 dev
drwxr-xr-x 45 root root  4096 2009-10-22 13:13 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:42 home
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    30 2009-10-22 12:24 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-2.6.26-2-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 2009-10-22 13:12 lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4 2009-10-22 12:22 lib64 -> /lib
drwx------  2 root root 16384 2009-10-22 12:22 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:22 media
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2009-08-30 20:39 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:22 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 52 root root     0 2009-10-22 12:53 proc
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 2009-10-22 13:26 root
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:42 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2008-09-16 00:22 selinux
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:22 srv
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     0 2009-10-22 12:53 sys
drwxrwxrwt  5 root root  4096 2009-10-22 13:26 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 2009-10-22 13:12 usr
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4096 2009-10-22 12:22 var
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    27 2009-10-22 12:24 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-amd64
```

Comment: Hmm, lib64 -> /lib may do the trick. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
total 84
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root  4096 Feb 19  2009 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root  4096 Feb 19  2009 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 18  2009 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Dec  4  2008 boot
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 12740 Oct 22 06:25 dev
drwxr-xr-x 66 root root  4096 Oct 13 15:04 etc
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Sep 14 16:44 home
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Sep 14 16:50 lib
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Feb 19  2009 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 19  2009 media
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Dec  4  2008 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 19  2009 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 98 root root     0 Jul 11 18:34 proc
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Sep 30 16:37 root
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 14 16:50 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 16  2008 selinux
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 19  2009 srv
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     0 Jul 11 18:34 sys
drwxrwxrwt  3 root root  4096 Sep 30 15:24 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Apr 16  2009 usr
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 Sep 30 15:33 var
```

Comment: That's strange, no sym links?

Comment: i have one symlink for lib64, but other than that nope...

Comment: Well, that was from my Linode, but I'm pretty sure the only difference between their debian distro and a standard one is the kernel.